# Elements missing in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Assume I have this in HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in response.Tags | filter : searchKey">
</div>
```

Also I have a text input with `searchKey` model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchKey">
```

`response.Tags` is an array of JSONs.

Now the problem is, there are some missing objects in UI populated by `ng-repeat` when its loaded by default. When I use the text input and filters the list, i can see the missing things.

What has gone wrong?

**Note** - there are no changes to the array. Elements are there. Once its loaded its not changed.

**Edit** 
This is raw data I receive. Could go up to 500 elements, nothing gets missed when there is only a few.

```
    {
"AlertCategoryID": 15,
"AlertName": "Disk Space Low",
"AlertType": "Warning",
"AlertMessage": "<data><summary>Available disk space (%) on drive _Total is less than 10%. Current value is 5%.</summary><detail></detail></data>",
"AlertTime": "2015-05-21T19:24:03"
    }, {
"AlertCategoryID": 15,
"AlertName": "Disk Space Low",
"AlertType": "Warning",
"AlertMessage": "<data><summary>Available disk space (%) on drive _Total is less than 10%. Current value is 5%.</summary><detail></detail></data>",
"AlertTime": "2015-05-21T19:22:05"
}
```

I use an XML parser to extract `<summary>` tag , also I intercept and removes the T between Date and Time; and assign these to the array which i will be using for ng-repeat.

I am showing the AlertName,  Message and the Time of it in the UI.

I noted that the elements which tend to lose have a very large XML in the message tag. I dont know if it has to do with anything.

Comment: Your `ng-model` says `searchQuery`, not `searchKey`

Comment: sorry its a typo here.

Comment: Don't type code here, **always** copy / paste

Comment: Can you give an example of `response.Tags` as well as what ends up missing on initial load? Even better would be a Plunker example

Comment: Thanks for the advice. wont do again.

Comment: @Phil , I did some edit. Does it give all the info u need?

Comment: Do you want a global filter or you just want filter objects based on specific properties like 'AlertName' ? For the latter see my answer below

Comment: @kachhalimbu, When I filter using a specific name, i can see some elements which I dont see in the initial load. I need to find out why they are missing and fix it.

Comment: the missing element could be most likely because of unknown/broken tags like `<data><summary>` etc. How are you displaying them? show your complete ng-repeat code.

Comment: use a `<pre>` tag to display `AlertMessage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78495/discussion-between-kachhalimbu-and-dandole).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter based on specific key in the JSON object use following syntax

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in response.Tags | filter:{ AlertName: searchKey }">
```